# Is it appropriate to say - "I am tired of your mischiefs?" or "Your mischiefs won't go unnoticed"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to use mischief as a **noun**. Above sentence sounds a little awkward as I have never seen anyone using it this way. Is there a more suitable replacement?

Answer (score 8):

*Mischief* is always a noun, but it is a non-count noun: it designates a kind or quality of behavior, not an individual instance of such behavior.  Thus you may say

> <sup>ok</sup> I am tired of your mischief. *BUT NOT*
>   <sup>∗</sup> I am tired of your mischiefs.

What word you use to designate individual instances will depend on exactly how you want to characterize the behavior.  *Mischief* is used colloquially mostly of behavior springing from exuberance and humour rather than real malice; if that is what you mean, *tricks* or *pranks* might work.

> I warn you, Sandeep: your tricks have not gone unnoticed.

In formal contexts, *mischief* has a graver sense, denoting in law malicious and wanton actions which cause damage or injury, and in other contexts the damaging consequences of action rather than the action itself:

> As serious as these problems were, they masked the real mischief created by Democratic state banking policies.

In the sense of consequences, plural *mischiefs* is not uncommon; but it is probably not what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the word mischief isn't really correct or comfortable used in that way.

You might use mischief in - 'I wonder what mischief the dog will get up to whilst I pop to the shops'.

The word mischief usually implies minor transgressions, naughty rather than malicious.

I would replace the word with shenanigans. The form and sound of the word reinforces the lighter meaning of mischief.

Comment: "Mischief" is fine. It's the attempted plural "*mischiefs" That's the problem.

Comment: Yes, and that was addressed earlier - here is an alternative as requested by the OP in the question at the end